# Bootstrap 5 Scrollspy activate.bs.scrollspy not working

Tags: bootstrap-5

I tried everything from the [doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/scrollspy/#how-it-works). The event is still not working. But the list is updating when I scroll. What I did:

1. Add `position: relative;` on the body.
2. Add `data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-target="#scroll-spy-nav" data-bs-offset="0" tabindex="0"` on the body.
3. Create the list:

> ```
> <div id="scroll-spy-nav" class="list-group position-fixed" style="top:0;">
>         <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#first-row">Item 1</a>
>         <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#row-sikisal-add">Item 
>   2</a>
>  </div>
> ```

The list is working fine because it is updated when I scroll.

Then in jQuery init:

```
$(()=>{
    // I tried
    $(window).on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function (ev, e) {
        console.log('sroll')
     }); 

    // I tried
    $("body").on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function (ev, e) {
        console.log('sroll')
     }); 

    // I tried
    $("#scroll-spy-nav").on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function (ev, e) {
        console.log('sroll')
     }); 

     // Also
     var firstScrollSpyEl = document.querySelector('[data-bs-spy="scroll"]')
    firstScrollSpyEl.addEventListener('activate.bs.scrollspy', function () {
        console.log('srolling')
    })
});
```

But, none of those got fired.

I'm using `"bootstrap": "^5.1.3",`. I had Bootstrap 4 and it work with `$(window)`.

Comment: What finally worked for you?

Comment: Bootstrap does not work with jQuery anymore. Use standard JS. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason `$(window).on('activate.bs.scrollspy', ...` does not work. It works with pure JS `window.addEventListener('activate.bs.scrollspy', ...`.